# How do you document a React Native/React/Node project within the team?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I would like to learn of ways that yourself or your team handles documentations within your JS-related projects, such as React, React Native, or Node. This includes custom hooks, API methods, usage guides, helper function usage or any other functional methods that requires a documentation to understand; that gives future code maintainers a common guide to understand the methods, without having to read the individual method codes.

I do have a few ways in mind:

1. Using `.txt` files within the JS project folders to note down example usage
2. Having a common text document stored somewhere within Google Docs, Word or related platforms
3. Having a TypeScript related documentation system

Does anyone have any such practices within your team, and how is it working out?

Comment: Yes, I know that `git` is used to collaborate code between developers. However, I am looking for a way to document the codes.

Comment: I have actually found a way to do this, using `JSDoc`. https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create markdown(.md) files inside the project depending upon your choice. It is obvious that you will be having different folders and subfolders inside your project. You can create markdown files inside every folder to describe the functions, features and their usage. In this way, you can keep the documentation close to the files containing the described functions.

Using markdown, you can explain the functions, logic, folder structure, etc, very nicely and add some usage code snippets, external links, images, etc in your description.

While working with the team, you might also be using some version control system like GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab, etc. When you will create the markdown files with the special name “README.md”, then these version control systems will display these README files automatically when you will open(navigate through) the particular folder on their websites.

You can make use of the tools like:

- https://readme.so/editor (My favourite)
- https://www.makeareadme.com/

to create the readme files very easily while getting the output of the markdown immidiately on the right panel.

Learning markdown is also very easy. There are very few basic things you are required to learn and the rest is upto you and how you use them. For example:

1. use `#` for adding headings
2. use `-` or `*` for adding list item
3. enclose the word or sentence inside back-ticks(`) to highlight them
4. to display the code block, enclose the code inside the pair of three back-ticks
5. use `[]()` for adding link

If you are looking for an advance tool, then https://docusaurus.io/ can be an awesome choice to focus only on your content and let the library take care of making easy to read documentation website for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks for the useful description of the basics of `.md` files, and for the recommended readme editors too!